# Laravel Nova: Username and Avatar do not update

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-nova, avatar

I noticed after updating the currently logged in user's Username and Avatar, the username and avatar in the top right corner do not update to the new data.

[Image of the username and Avatar not matching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8uAs.png)

I know refreshing the page updates the username and avatar in the top right corner, but is there a way to have them automatically update when the user's information is updated?